# An inequality about median of points in higher dimensions

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, optimization, linear-algebra, high-dimensional-geometry

Let $S$ be a set of points in $\mathbf{R^d}$ and let $m$ be the median of this set of points, i.e. $\sum_{x \in S} || x - y||$ is minimized when we have $y=m$. Now let $z$ be an arbitrary point in $\mathbf{R^d}$. *Is the following true?*

$$\sum_{x \in S} ||x-z|| \leq K \cdot (\sum_{x \in S} ||x-m|| + |S| \cdot ||m-z||)$$
where $K$ is a constant.

We know that if we replace all the $||a-b||$ expressions by $||a-b||^2$, and we consider the mean instead of the median(i.e. replace $m$ with $\mu$), then actually we will have equality and $K=1$. So I want to know if similar things hold for the median.

I was thinking maybe the following is true. Is it?

$$\sum_{x \in S} ||x-z|| \leq \cdot (\sum_{x \in S} ||x-m|| + 4|S| \cdot ||m-z||)$$

Comment: Doesn't triangle inequality give you $\| x - z\| \le \|x - m\| + \|m - z\|$?  In which case the inequality holds even with $K=1$ and replacing "$|S|$" with 1.  And for arbitrary $m$? What am I missing?

Comment: @NealYoung The $|S|$ thing is still needed, as you are summing $|S|$ triangle inequalities together.

Comment: Oh, I thought that term was inside the summand.  It makes more sense that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By the triangle inequality, $\|x-z\| \le \|x-m\| + \|m -z\|$, which implies the desired inequality (with $K=1$) for any $m$ and $z$.